# Some program is making connections to an unknown subnet, but couldn't find the process that initiates the connection

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking, port

We have a server that is making a lot of outbound connections to a particular subnet, I am not able to find out what process is making it.

I could see the connections in tcdump -

```
[root@something ~]# tcpdump -i ens192 -v | grep 26379
tcpdump: listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
    hosname.sometohing.43494 > 172.31.20.63.26379: Flags [S], cksum 0xe734 (incorrect -> 0xe6c9), seq 258461406, win 26720, options [mss 1336,sackOK,TS val 1947447040 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    hosname.sometohing.43494 > 172.31.20.63.26379: Flags [S], cksum 0xe734 (incorrect -> 0xe2dd), seq 258461406, win 26720, options [mss 1336,sackOK,TS val 1947448044 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    hosname.sometohing.37346 > 172.31.42.22.26379: Flags [S], cksum 0xfd0b (incorrect -> 0x5843), seq 1954738294, win 26720, options [mss 1336,sackOK,TS val 1947449600 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    hosname.sometohing.37454 > 172.31.42.22.26379: Flags [S], cksum 0xfd0b (incorrect -> 0xe93e), seq 1610576711, win 26720, options [mss 1336,sackOK,TS val 1947449675 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    hosname.sometohing.43494 > 172.31.20.63.26379: Flags [S], cksum 0xe734 (incorrect -> 0xdb09), seq 258461406, win 26720, options [mss 1336,sackOK,TS val 1947450048 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

I am trying the lsof to see if finds something, but nothing for 2 minutes, but tcpdump keeps printing that host is sending traffic.

```
while true; do lsof -i | grep 172.31;done
```

And then netstat with all possible switches. `antp`, `vunp`, `vutp`, `e`, `o` and everything I could think of. I don't see any output.

I would be really grateful for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: How often do these SYN packets arrive? What is the configuration of `ens192` interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [bpf-tools](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2019-01-01/learn-ebpf-tracing.html)  and run [tcpconnect](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcpconnect_example.txt). Every connect() will be traced to get its PID and COMM, which is actually lightweight compared to packet capture.

Also take a packet capture, run it through Wireshark, and see what protocols are revealed with the dissectors.

Comment: I will try this and comment the outcome here, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had this issue before, but I expect netstat will assist you.  Try running

```
  netstat -tup
```

This will show you a list of tcp and udp connections.  The last column will hopefully show you a PID / Program Name to allow you to identify the associated process.